# Modify Email Alert for a Specific List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am using SharePoint 2010.

For one particular list on my site I would like to modify the email text received when a user receives an alert.

I would like to replace the text `Modify my alert settings|View Calendar1|Mobile View` with static text of my own.

Essentially I have a distribution list hooked up to this alert so it's confusing to the user for the email to tell them to go to My Alerts to discontinue receiving alerts.

I have looked at the alerttemplates.xml file but I have no idea what part to modify or if that's how I should do this.

I only want this change to apply to a few specific lists, not on all lists on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Customizing the email alert text in any fashion is not a trivial matter.  If you would like to go that route, the proper way is a custom feature, and I have seen plenty of feedback that customizing the alerts is much more difficult than was anticipated.

There may be an easier way to solve your problem.  In my company's case, we found it much easier to set up a SharePoint Designer workflow to send out the email with the exact text we needed.  The only drawback here is that individual users cannot subscribe ad-hoc to the alerts using the ribbon.  For example, there would have to be a particular group that they would need to be added to in order to get the emails, and this would need to be communicated to them somehow.

Comment: Users will not be subscribing ad-hoc. It will be managed through a group anyways. Can you point me in the direction of how to capture this information in a workflow? ie. How do I trigger a workflow every morning at 7AM that will figure out all the event changes in the past 24 hours?

Comment: We use this free solution to schedule workflows in our farm:   [link](http://www.harepoint.com/products/harepointworkflowscheduler/default.aspx).

Comment: ...ran out of time to edit above....        However, you may not need a daily digest as SharePoint can automatically trigger a workflow on item change/create as well.  Regardless, if you used the scheduler, I would have the workflow use the following pseudocode:  `for each item in your list` `if last modified greater than now minus 24 hours then append info to email text` `send email`

Comment: ok great, didn't realize there was a last modified field, I will look into that. However, I'm also interested in what the change actually is...